# Watching YouTube videos through browser in Android app

Tags: android, youtube

I'm writing an android app that has video content and references videos on YouTube. I implemented code in the Android 2.3 SDK and it properly runs. However, my phone updated to Android 4.0 and now the activity force closes. The activity simply uses image and text views to link, not a video view. What is the proper way to implement this activity in 4.0 that is backwards compatible with 2.3?

Comment: Check for any `Network requests`. I guess you are calling them from `UI thread`

Comment: any stack traces for the force close?

Comment: The stack trace for the force close says that the sources for InvocationTargetException.class and ThreadGroup.class cannot be found.